# Proof that $||a| - |b|| \leq |a-b|$ using Cauchy-Schwarz-Inequality

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I would like to prove that $||a| - |b|| \leq |a-b|$ holds für $a,b \in \mathbb{R^n}$

Most proofs I found only consider $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, moreover, I wanted to utilize the Cauchy Schwarz inequality to prove the above inequality. So far my approach is:

\begin{align*}
    &\hspace{1cm}||a| - |b|| \leq |a-b| \\
    &\Longleftrightarrow (|a| - |b|)^2 \leq |a-b|^2 \\
    &\Longleftrightarrow |a|^2 - 2|a||b| + |b|^2 \leq |a|^2 - 2\langle a,b \rangle + |b|^2 \\
    &\Longleftrightarrow  -2|a||b| \leq -2\langle a,b \rangle \\
    &\Longleftrightarrow  |a||b| \geq \langle a,b \rangle
\end{align*}

where $|a||b| \geq \langle a,b \rangle$ is already proven by the Cauchy Schwarz Inequality. I am not sure if the second step ($||a| - |b|| = (|a| - |b|)^2$)  and last step (reversing the inequality sign) are correct though, and if I can start a proof by changing both sides of the inequality at the same time. Most times I see people start with one side and arrive at the other?

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: Proof's fine, agreeing with Berci ;)

Comment: Note that your proof works only for the Euclidean norm on $\Bbb R^n$, wich is induced by an inner product. The original inequality holds for any norm, though.

Comment: @MartinR you mean that the proof would not work for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What I mean is that your proof works if $|a|$ is defined as $\langle a, a \rangle = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2}$. But there are other norms on $\Bbb R^n$, e.g. $|a| = \max a_i$ or $|a| = |a_1| + \cdots + |a_n|$.